Quarkus and SQL Cloud GCP
I have this problem with send a petition to REST API. My service runs in GKE.
The Vertx instance must use a native transport in order to connect to connect through domain socketsclass java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
My pom.xml is this
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pe.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>generate-quarkus-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.10.0</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.2.5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-qute</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.glxn.qrgen</groupId>
      <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.newrelic.agent.java</groupId>
      <artifactId>newrelic-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.9.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Reactive uses the reactive-pg-client with PostgreSQL under the hood -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
      <version>1.15.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-transport-native-unix-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Unzip New Relic Java agent into target/ -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>unpack-newrelic</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includeGroupIds>com.newrelic.agent.java</includeGroupIds>
              <includeArtifactIds>newrelic-java</includeArtifactIds>
              <!-- you can optionally exclude files -->
              <!-- <excludes>**/newrelic.yml</excludes> -->
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>

My properties file is this
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql 
quarkus.datasource.username=xxxxxx
quarkus.datasource.password=yyyyyy
google.application-credentials=${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://:5432/qr-database?host=/cloudsql/${DB_URL}
quarkus.vertx.prefer-native-transport=true
quarkus.reactive.implementation = smallrye

When I test with a diferent database works it, but with Cloud SQL doesn't work.

Proxy Google Cloud SQL
- name: cloud-sql-proxy
  image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.8.0
  args:
    - "--structured-logs"
    - "--port=<DB_PORT>"
    - "<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>"

  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "2Gi"
      cpu:    "1"

